# Find all integers $m$ and $n$ such that $n\cos\frac{\pi}{m}= \sqrt{8+\sqrt{32+\sqrt{768}}}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find all integers $m$ and $n$ such that: 
>   $$n\cos\frac{\pi}{m}= \sqrt{8+\sqrt{32+\sqrt{768}}}$$

I tried to find the relation of $m$ and $n$, but it's difficult for me. I need help! Thanks!

Comment: I would try half-angle formula.

Comment: Write $$\sqrt {32+\sqrt {768}}$$ as $$2\sqrt 2(\sqrt 3+1)$$

Answer (score 3):

$$8+\sqrt{32+\sqrt{768}}=8+\sqrt{8(\sqrt3+1)^2}=8\left(1+\dfrac{\sqrt3+1}{2\sqrt2}\right)=8(1+\cos(60-45)^\circ)=16\cos^2(7.5^\circ)$$

Answer (score 2):

By applying the formula
$$\cos x=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(2x)}2}$$
three times, you can obtain $n\cos k=$
[image]

By direct comparison, $$n= 4$$
$$\cos 8k=\frac12\implies 8k=\pm \frac\pi3$$
Thus, $m=\pm24$.

To prove uniqueness, consider
$$|m|\ge2\implies\frac1{|m|}\le\frac12\implies \frac\pi{|m|}\le\frac\pi2$$

In the region, cosine is positive. Thus, $n>0$.

For a moment, assume $m>0$.

Since $n\cos x$ is strictly decreasing in the region $0\le x\le\pi/2$, it intersects a single value(a horizontal line) at most once. Thus $m=24, n=4$ is the unique solution for $m,n>0$.

Exploiting the evenness of cosine, $m=-24, n=4$ is also a solution.

**ADDED:**

One may question whether, with $a,b,c,d$
natural numbers and $b,d$ non-square numbers, the following is true:
$$\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{c+\sqrt{d}}\implies a=c, b=d$$

Suppose $a\ne c, b\ne d$, $a,b,c,d$ are natural numbers, $b,d$ non square numbers.

Manipulating $\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{c+\sqrt{d}}$ by repeatedly squaring both sides and rearranging to get rid of square roots, one obtains

$$((a-c)^2-(b-d))^2=4(a-c)^2d$$

Note that the left hand side is a square number, thus so as the right hand side. Then, this requires either $d$ to be a square number, or $(a-c)=0$, which both oppose our supposition.

Thus, $$\sqrt{a+\sqrt{b}}=\sqrt{c+\sqrt{d}}\implies a=c, b=d$$ is true.

Similarly, the direct comparison I made is therefore justified.

**p.s.** Personally, I like @labbhattacharjee ‘s answer more than mine. His answer doesn’t require the ADDED part proof. Well, I think of half angle formula because of the square roots; his answer needs some math sense to see the hidden $\cos(60-45)$.

Comment: How do you know this is the only possibility?

Comment: @Micah I didn’t claim that...

Comment: Fair enough, but without some argument in that direction this doesn't really answer the question...

Comment: @Micah I’ve added...

Comment: Your argument shows that if $n=4$, then $m=24$ is the unique (positive) solution. It has nothing to say about other values of $n$. Indeed, if $n \geq 4$, we can always use the intermediate value theorem to find some real number $m$ which satisfies the identity. The question is, when will that $m$ be an integer?

Comment: @Micah See my edited answer.